# How to think of Sobolev spaces $W^{k, p}$ for a function that is no longer an element of $W^{k, p}$ for $p$ greater than some number?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Consider the function $u(x) = x^{\frac{1}{2}}$ on the domain $[0, 1]$. This function is an element of $W^{1, 1}$ and $W^{1, \infty}$ but not $W^{1, 2}$ as

1. for $W^{1, 1}$, we have $\Vert\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\Vert_1 = 1 < \infty$.
2. for $W^{1, \infty}$, we have $\Vert\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\Vert_\infty = \frac{1}{2} < \infty$.
3. for $W^{1, 2}$, we have $\Vert\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\Vert_2 = \frac{1}{4}(\ln 1 - \ln 0) = \infty$.

In fact, $u \in W^{1,p}$ only if $p < 2$ or $p = \infty$. What intuition should I take from this situation? If I take $p < 2$ and gradually let it approach I can see that $u$ from evaluating $\Vert\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\Vert_p$ that $u$ is getting 'closer and closer' to not being an element of $W^{1,p}$. How does someone with experience of Sobolev spaces view this phenomenon?

Comment: Check your calculations - you should have $\Vert u_x \Vert_p \to \Vert u_x \Vert_\infty$ as $p \to \infty$. In particular the gradient $u_x$ is unbounded as $x \to 0$, so your second point is incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your phenomenon cannot be true as we have $W^{1,p}(0,1) \subseteq W^{1,q}(0,1)$ if $1 \leq q < p \leq \infty$. And indeed, for $1 \leq p < \infty$, we have

$$ \int_0^1 u'(x)^p \, dx = \frac{1}{2^p} \int_0^1 x^{-\frac{p}{2}} \, dx = \begin{cases} 
-\frac{1}{2^p \left( \frac{p}{2} - 1 \right)} \left(1 - \lim_{x \to 0} x^{-\frac{p}{2} + 1} \right) & p \neq 2, \\
-\frac{1}{4} \lim_{x \to 0} \ln(x) & p = 2.
\end{cases} $$

Thus, the integral converges if and only $-\frac{p}{2} + 1 > 0$ or $1 \leq p < 2$.

For $p = \infty$, we have

$$ ||u'(x)||_{\infty} = \sup_{x \in [0,1]} \left| \frac{1}{2} x^{-\frac{1}{2}} \right| = \infty $$

which implies that $u \in W^{1,p}$ if and only if $1 \leq p < 2$.

Comment: Ok thanks for spotting the mistake. So is this the point of Sobolev spaces? To find the variables that 'break' a solution? Is it a bad thing thing that $1 \le p < 2$? Would it be a better situation if we had $1 \le p < 5$ for example?

Comment: Well, if the range would have been $1 \leq p < 5$ then the function would have more regularity with respect to the scale determined by the Sobolev spaces. Intuitively, $u \in W^{k,p}(\Omega)$ with $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ has $k - \frac{n}{p}$ "derivatives" (this intuition is justified by the various embedding theorems for Sobolev spaces) and so as $p$ is larger, the function has "more derivatives".

Comment: If $k = 1, n = p = 2$, then we have $u$ has no 'derivatives'? Yet $u$ should have $1$ derivative as it is in $W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R^2})$? In what sense do you mean derivatives

Comment: This is a bit complicated to explain. If $r$ is an integer and $r < k - \frac{n}{p} < r + 1$ then we expect that $f \in W^{k,p}(\Omega)$ will have $r$ classical continuous derivatives and in fact $f \in C^{k, r + 1 - k + \frac{n}{p}}(\Omega)$ so the $k$ derivatives are Holder continuous with exponent $(r + 1) - \left( k - \frac{n}{p} \right)$. This indeed happens under certain assumptions as guaranteed by the Sobolev embedding theorem. Motivated by this, it might seem plausible that If $k - \frac{n}{p}$ is an integer, $f$ should have $k - \frac{n}{p}$ classical continuous derivatives but this

Comment: is precisely the limit case for the Sobolev embeddings and it doesn't hold in general (unless $n = 1$). If $k = 1, n = 2$ and $p > 2$ then $0 < k - \frac{n}{p} < 1$ and indeed $u$ will be continuous (possibly after redefining $u$ on a null set) and even Holder continuous. If $p = 2$ then $k - \frac{n}{p} = 0$ and so we might expect that $u$ will be continuous but this doesn't hold. The same goes if $p < 2$.

Comment: Ok thanks for the detailed explanation!